# jQuery insertAfter has strange behavior

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move a div that contains an object element that contains a JW Player. The div looks like this, where it's currently nestled between some p elements:
[image]

The view above is from the Firebug HTML panel.

The jQuery I'm using is

```
                $('#container_wrapper').insertAfter('p#crown_li');
```

After this executes, the player is no longer visible and the HTML looks like this:[image]

The div and the object moved to where they should have, but the object element is faded and it no longer displays on the page.

Does anyone know what might have happened?

Thanks

Comment: can you paste html code so i can test it..?

Comment: `$('p#hand_li').insertAfter('#container_wrapper');` why don't you try this?

Comment: $('#container_wrapper').insertAfter('#crown_li'); have you tried this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a flash object element in the DOM is poorly supported in various browsers. Could you move the `container_wrapper` before you initialize jwplayer?

Comment: Dipesh: Sorry.  I don't have anyhthing I can paste.

Comment: Jai: The idea is to move the player (container_wrapper) to be beneath the mp3 that is currently playing.  To move the titles instead I'd have to move all of them.

Comment: sasi: That fails the same way.

Comment: Texaxa: Yes, I think you're right about moving flash objects being poorly supported.  The code actually works fine on Chrome and Safari, works for some moves on Firefox, and never works on IE. It is curious, though, that Firebug saw the code and knew it wasn't going to display so it faded the text.  What did Firebug see?

Comment: @Steve I haven't used jwplayer, but I suppose the gui is inside the flash? You could take a look at http://www.jplayer.org/ it's a flash/html5 media player with the gui in html which would allow you to leave the player where it is and just move the gui.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their comments.